# Eclipse m2e doesn't doesn't allow a SNAPSHOT dependency and its project open in the workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, snapshot

I have a very strange problem with SNAPSHOT dependencies in maven + Eclipse (m2e).
In the project AuditingWebService-installer I have a dependency on IDS-Utils-1.3.2-SNAPSHOT that is also an open project in my workspace. If I maintain opened the IDS-Utils project I have an error on the AuditingWebService (Missing artifact it.ids:IDS-Utils:jar:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT). I have to close the IDS-Utils project to clean the error. Why? This occurs only in SNAPSHOT dependencies, not in release.
Obviously maven from command line compiles correctly.

P.S. I have set "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" to false because WTP doesn't work correctly if the importing project is launched as a webapp.

[image: This is the workspace situation]